# Largest extinct clade?

Tags: taxonomy, extinction

What is the largest (by large I mean most general) clade of organisms that has gone extinct?

domain > kingdom > phylum > class > order > family > genus > species

So, for example, an extinct kingdom would be larger than an extinct class.

Comment: What do you mean by large? Do you mean in terms of number of species, number of individuals, weight of the individuals, ...? Is there any reason why you wrote the taxonomic ranks at the end of your question?

Comment: domain > kingdom > phylum > class > order > family > genus > species

Comment: added a comment to clear this up

Comment: @futurebird those are **not** clades, those are simply taxonomic ranks of taxa. Not all taxa are clades (most of them, by the way, are not). And, unlike clades, taxonomic ranks are totally, completely arbitrary.

Comment: @futurebird There are genuses that contain more species than some classes.

Comment: Sometimes an entire phylum has just one species.

Comment: I'm not interested in the number of species, I'm interested in extinct creatures most genetically distant from everything alive today.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics aside, I think the OP wants a group of animals which are  grouped together as related and which are extinct.  I propose **trilobites**.  They are no more but at one time they ruled the earth.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilobite

> Trilobites ( /ˈtraɪləˌbaɪt, ˈtrɪ-, -loʊ-/;[2][3] meaning "three
>   lobes") are a fossil group of extinct marine arachnomorph arthropods
>   that form the class Trilobita. Trilobites form one of the earliest
>   known groups of arthropods. The first appearance of trilobites in the
>   fossil record defines the base of the Atdabanian stage of the Early
>   Cambrian period (521 million years ago), and they flourished
>   throughout the lower Paleozoic era before beginning a drawn-out
>   decline to extinction when, during the Devonian, all trilobite orders
>   except the Proetids died out. Trilobites disappeared in the mass
>   extinction at the end of the Permian about 252 million years ago. The
>   trilobites were among the most successful of all early animals,
>   roaming the oceans for over 270 million years.[4]